# download file from internet returns error 400 on Java, on browser works ok

Tags: java

I need to download a file using java from this webpage
[http://www.okaa.gr/files/1/%CE%9F%CE%9A%CE%91%CE%91/%CE%A4%CE%99%CE%9C%CE%95%CE%A3 %CE%A7%CE%9F%CE%9D%CE%94%CE%A1%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%97%CE%A3/20150409-pasxa.pdf](http://www.okaa.gr/files/1/%CE%9F%CE%9A%CE%91%CE%91/%CE%A4%CE%99%CE%9C%CE%95%CE%A3%20%CE%A7%CE%9F%CE%9D%CE%94%CE%A1%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%97%CE%A3/20150409-pasxa.pdf)

the text there is in greek letters.
If you use this url on a browser, it works ok, and it opens up a pdf file. using it in Java, i get a 400 error.
I have used a bunch of different methods that supposingly do what i want, but they all get the same error.
This does work for a different site and a different file

```
    String okaa="http://www.okaa.gr/";
    String link="gr/nea-kai-anakoinoseis/statistika-deltia-timon/?date=09&month=4&year=2015&catname=0";
     URL okaaLink = new URL(okaa+link);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
     new InputStreamReader(okaaLink.openStream()));
     ArrayList<String> links =new ArrayList<String>();
               
     String inputLine;
     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
           if(inputLine.contains(".pdf"))
                {
                    String newLink=inputLine.substring(inputLine.indexOf("href")+6,inputLine.indexOf("download")-2);
                    links.add(okaa+newLink);    
                    }
                }
                
    in.close();

ArrayList<String> links =new ArrayList<String>();
links.add(url);  //the url in question  
for (int i=0;i<links.size();i++)
    {
//   download and save the file
        URL website = new URL(links.get(i));//the url link
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());    
                       
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(i+".pdf");             
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);            
        fos.close();    
}
```

Any help?

Edit:
Updated code. I first read from the main page the list of the links, strip the html parts (the substring command) and pass it to the ArrayList.
Then using the urls on the array list i want to download the files
But this doesnt work even if i copy the url fromthe browser and paste it directly in the command `URL website = new URL("....");`

Solved:

Thanks @Yannick, all i had to do was remove the spaces using `newLink=newLink.replaceAll("\\s","");`

I would NEVER figured it out!

Comment: What is `links`? Is this some file? How is it encoded?

Comment: @Tichodroma updated question. its an arraylist having the urls in String format

Comment: Are you sure you aren't encoding an URL that's already encoded?

Comment: no, i am not sure to be honest. I just used the same code as i used before to download an xls file.

Comment: Now show us how you set the value of `url`.

Comment: That's not the URL you mention in your question.

Comment: @Tichodroma the first one yoiu mean?link=..., no that is a page containend the links to the files. i scan that page, get the links and save them to array list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that the link contains a space at

> ...%A3 %CE...

Your browser automatically replaces " " with "", because links with a space are not valid.

The solution of **newuserua_ext** doesn't contain this space and that could be the reason that it works.

Answer (score 0):

That's what i tried and downloaded pdf file ;

```
ArrayList<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();

    links.add("http://www.okaa.gr/files/1/%CE%9F%CE%9A%CE%91%CE%91/%CE%A4%CE%99%CE%9C%CE%95%CE%A3%20%CE%A7%CE%9F%CE%9D%CE%94%CE%A1%CE%99%CE%9A%CE%97%CE%A3/20150409-pasxa.pdf");

    for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("opening connection");
        URL url = new URL(links.get(i));

        InputStream in = url.openStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(i + ".pdf"));

        System.out.println("reading file...");
        int length = -1;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];// buffer for portion of data from
                                // connection
        while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        fos.close();
        in.close();
        System.out.println("file was downloaded");
    }
```

**Output;**

[image: Output]

Comment: ok, now i am really confused! i copied your code and still got the same error (400) there is something wrong with my setup!
It didnt pass through InputStream in1 = url.openStream();

Comment: Did you try with your own links list or with mine?

Comment: Whait!, What!
how is it possible. before, i kept my own ArrayList, since i needed it, but now i copied the whole thing from your answer and works!
Why?! whats the difference?

Comment: You should compare what is the difference between mine and your. Maybe charset problem maybe something else.